# Adding related resources or hyperlinks in edits

Tags: discussion, support, comments, edits, suggested-edits

So, I've been rejecting the addition of resources/hyperlinks to posts simply because I had no idea that this was an acceptable practice.  Today, I was browsing through the edits page and saw:

> Some common reasons to edit are:
>
> - to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes
> - to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it
> - to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages
> - **to add related resources or hyperlinks**

Why is this an acceptable practice?  I can see adding links to official documentation, but the quality of outside resources is (potentially) subjective.  I see the merit in adding resources, but it seems to me that these additional resources **should be placed in comments, not inserted into the post via an edit**.  Anyone have thoughts on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ideal Stack Exchange post does not have any comments. A comment indicates an unresolved issue in the post, usually either a request for clarification or an observation of the flaw that the observer is unable to correct. This is explained in [the page that describes the comment privilege](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Adding supplemental information is preferably done inline, so that the information is where it belongs. Links should be used directly on the concept they are illustrating, so that clicking on a word or phrase leads to a page providing supplemental information about the linked word. A list of links at the end is only useful if the link is of general interest, and then it's probably not relevant enough to add to an answer (a comment with a link might be ok for a question, in an “the answer may be found there but I don't have time to dig through it now” way; that's an unresolved issue, which can be resolved by writing a proper answer). [Wikipedia recommends inline citations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:INCITE#WP:INCITE) with a similar reasoning (keep the basis for a statement close to that statement).

Remember that the intent of a post is to be read. When you review an edit, your driving guideline should be: does this edit make the post better? Adding a link to a relevant resource makes the post better, so it should be accepted. When reviewing a suggested edit, it's your job to evaluate whether the resource is relevant and worth linking to. The answer is generally yes for links to reference or well-known site (e.g. the main site of a software project, a Wikipedia page explaining a concept). If the link is to some site of unknown reliability (e.g. a blog post) and you don't know enough about the subject matter to ascertain the quality of the link, skip.

This bears repeating, because it seems that reviewers sometimes forget it: **if you don't know whether a suggested edit is correct, skip it**. A vast majority of suggested edits don't require any subject matter, but for those that do, you should only accept or reject if you do have the requisite knowledge.

And remember, the key question is, [**does this edit make the post better**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/editing). Clarifying an explanation, correcting a minor mistake, or adding relevant supplemental information make the post better. Reject suggestions that are incorrect or that change the post so much that they should be posted separately.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/editing

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:INCITE

Comment: Wow, thanks for the response.  I did not realize that this is how SO was supposed to be.  Learn something new everyday.

Comment: I see what you did there...

Comment: @CodyGray Thank you for completing the object lesson.