# Approving suggested edits that link references to an answer

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

Should we approve edits that do nothing except adding relevant links to Wikipedia pages that correspond to the topic being discussed?

Case in point- [This edit](https://security.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/89238) just adds 2 Wikipedia links, which IMO does *clearly improve the post* which is the standard for approving edits. However, if that sets a precedent, similar edits can then be made to a large number of SE posts.

Comment: Links are a distraction from the main body of the post. They should only be added if they add value. Links to Wikipedia rarely add value to a post. Type any of these concepts in your favorite search engine and you'll get the Wikipedia item top of the list. Google even one-boxed them.

Comment: @S.L.Barth, inline links to the top Wikipedia article can make the post easier to read, thereby adding value. In fact, [Wikipedia's recommendation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style/Linking#What_generally_should_be_linked) seems to encourage links that connect to the subject of the article, as does the [relevant meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192400/adding-related-resources-or-hyperlinks-in-edits).

Comment: @S.L.Barth, considering that you rejected [the edit](https://security.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/89238), but it seems to have been approved, the policy around links is still unclear to me. The duplicate post also seems to indicate that approving the edit was the right decision. While links can be a distraction, perhaps this involves a larger discussion around the correct level of links in posts...